# How can I turn the vector c('foo', 'bar', 'baz') into c('foo_X', 'foo_Y', 'bar_X', 'bar_Y', 'baz_X', 'baz_Y')?

Tags: r, vector

Here's a simple vector:

```
vec <- c('foo', 'bar', 'baz');
```

I want to add the suffixes `_X` and `_Y` to each element of this vector, so that I get a vector with six elements: `c('foo_X', 'foo_Y', 'bar_X', 'bar_Y', 'baz_X', 'baz_Y')`.

I hoped that I could achieve that with `sapply`:

```
sapply(vec, function(elem) {
        c(paste0(elem, '_X'),
          paste0(elem, '_Y'))
     });
```

However, this returns a matrix rather than a vector:

```
     foo     bar     baz    
[1,] "foo_X" "bar_X" "baz_X"
[2,] "foo_Y" "bar_Y" "baz_Y"
```

What can I do to create the vector I want?

Comment: `c(result)` works too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `outer` with `paste0`

```
vec <- c('foo', 'bar', 'baz')
suffix <- c("_X", "_Y")
c(outer(vec, suffix, paste0))
#[1] "foo_X" "bar_X" "baz_X" "foo_Y" "bar_Y" "baz_Y"
```